# How to pass gnuplot a matrix in c?

Tags: c, matrix, pipe, gnuplot

I'm using pipes to call gnuplot directly in C. I open the pipe using:

```
#define GNUPLOT "gnuplot -persist"
FILE *gp;
gp = popen(GNUPLOT, "w");
```

Right now, I want to pass a matrix, say `zvalue[][]`, to gnuplot so that I can use the following command to plot a 3D graph:

```
fprintf(gp, "splot zvalue matrix using 1:2:3\n");
```

I managed to do this when using pipes in C++:

```
#include "gnuplot-iostream.h"
```

which needs to compile using `-lboost_iostreams -lboost_system -lboost_filesystem`, and it has a function `gp.fileld(zvalue)` to deal with this, which is:

```
gp << "splot" << gp.file1d(zvalue) << "matrix using 1:2:3\n";
```

so that gnuplot can get access to the matrix `zvalue`.

My question is, is there a similar function using C pipes?

Comment: Please format your code.

Answer (score 0):

You must use the special file name `-` with `splot` and then write your matrix data to the pipe:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define GNUPLOT "gnuplot -persist"

int main(void)
{
    FILE *gp = popen(GNUPLOT, "w");

    fprintf(gp, "splot '-' matrix using 1:2:3\n");
    int i, j;
    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < 10; j++)
            fprintf(gp, "%d ", i*j);
        fprintf(gp, "\n");
    }
    pclose(gp);
    return 0;
}
```

Of course, in your case you must write `fprintf(gp, "%e ", zvalue[i][j])` or similar.

Comment: Thanks for you answer, I have thought the same way, I'm just hoping an easier way like in C++. And in your code, fprintf(gp, "\n") should be modified into fprintf(gp, "e"), right?

Comment: No, printing the new line is correct. This marks the end of a matrix row. An `e` would be necessary at the end, but since the pipe is closed after having sent all data, this isn't necessary. But how simply are you expecting this to become? Just encapsulate this in a short function which sends the splot command and the matrix over the pipe. I think this is the easiest way, no external stuff involved.

Comment: Just to make sure I can follow you. In your code, you are filling the matrix, and splot zvalue w lines using 1:2:3 means plots a x-y grid with zvalue on each point (i,j)? So, I can also use another way, that is: splot '-' w lines, then enter the point one by one, this time (i,j,z[i][j]), and put 'e\n' at the end?

Comment: Basically, in the for loops I only construct a data format gnuplot understands (in this case in `matrix` format). For the format it doesn't matter if you write the data to a file and read with gnuplot from that file, or if you pass it via a pipe and the special `-` file name. You can send data in any format, gnuplot understands, also as `fprintf(fp, "%d %d %e\n", i, j, zvalue[i][j])`. Then you must make sure, you write an additional, empty line when `i` is increased, to get the correct data format.

Comment: Hi, Chris, I checked your code today, it works on one matrix, but when I deal with two matrices, that is 'splot '-' matrix using 1:2:3 w point, '-' matrix using 1:2:3 w point \n', and after fill in the first matrix, I use 'fprintf(gp, "e\n")', however, it doesnot work, and gives error code 'Scan size of matrix is zero'. Hence, I need to reuse my way, that is, splot all the matrix point by point.

Comment: Yes, the code is for a single matrix, not for an arbitrary combination of several matrices. If you want to plot two matrices you must send both to gnuplot, separated by an 'e'. Since you don't show full examples it's quite tedious to find out what you are really doing...

Comment: Hi, yes, I passed both matrix to gnuplot, seperated by 'e', but does not work. Maybe I have typo, but I checked for several times.. Anyway, I get it running by passing my method, that is splot (i,j,zvalue[i][j]) point by point.

Comment: Hi, Christoph, could you answer this question for me? I really need help with pm3d splot. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29512860/how-to-pass-gnuplot-a-matrix-and-splot-pm3d-map-in-c