# How to pass gnuplot a matrix and splot pm3d map in c?

Tags: matrix, gnuplot

So, this time, I have a matrix called `zvalue[10][10]`, and I would like to draw a `pm3d` map, with normal `x-y` grids, and with `zvalue[i][j]` to be the value of point `(i,j)`.

In gnuplot, I just use:

```
set pm3d map
splot zvalue matrix using 1:2:3 with pm3d
```

And in `C++` gnuplot pipes, I can use a function `gp.file1d()` to achieve this.

```
gp << "splot" << gp.file1d(matrix) << "matrix using 2:1:3" << "with pm3d\n"
```

But now, I am in C gnuplot pipe, of course I can write the matrix into a file called `zvalue.txt`, and use the following:

```
fprintf(gp, "splot \"zvalue.txt\" matrix using 1:2:3 with pm3d\n")
```

But is there other way? I tried @Christ's suggestion when I deal with normal splot with matrix, that is do something like:

```
int main(void)
{
    FILE *gp = popen(GNUPLOT, "w");

    fprintf(gp, "splot '-' matrix using 1:2:3\n");
    int i, j;
    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < 10; j++)
            fprintf(gp, "%d ", i*j);
        fprintf(gp, "\n");
    }
    pclose(gp);
    return 0;
}
```

But when it's `pm3d`, it does not work well. I also tried with `splot` point by point, which works well for nomal splot with matrix, but here with `pm3d`, nothing works.

Comment: Please take some time and read http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking to get started with how stackoverflow works. Especially how your not-working (but full) example with pm3d looks like. And please also have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help to see how to properly format a question. That makes it much easier for others to read your question and to help.

Comment: Thanks for reminding, I will take a look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following script works fine with `pm3d`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define GNUPLOT "gnuplot -persist"

int main(void)
{
    FILE *gp = popen(GNUPLOT, "w");

    fprintf(gp, "set pm3d map\n");
    fprintf(gp, "splot '-' matrix using 1:2:3 with pm3d\n");
    int i, j;
    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < 10; j++)
            fprintf(gp, "%d ", i*j);
        fprintf(gp, "\n");
    }
    pclose(gp);
    return 0;
}
```

[image]

So if you have a program which makes use of `pm3d` and doesn't work, it would really help to see exactly *that* full file (so that one can copy&paste the code to compile and test it).